# How to change a windows service account using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wmi

I am trying to use python to change a service account password.
I have gone the wmi route:
This is my code:

```py
import secrets
import wmi
import getpass
import subprocess
import sys

c = wmi.WMI()

username = str.casefold("maria")

pwd = getpass.getpass()
services = list()

def Find_Service(username, pwd):
    for s in c.Win32_Service():
        if username in str.casefold(str(s.StartName)):
            print (str(s.Name))
            change_CMD = ("(, , , , , , , ")
            passwd = ( "'" + pwd + "')")
            print (change_CMD + passwd)
            s.Change(str(change_CMD + passwd))
```

When I run it, it errors with:

```
Password:
MariaDB
(, , , , , , , 'sdf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lmaclachlan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 440, in __call__
    parameter.Value = arg
  File "C:\Users\lmaclachlan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 686, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemProperty', 'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lmaclachlan\OneDrive - Unitec IT Solutions\Documents\dev\services.py", line 28, in <module>
    Find_Service(username, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\lmaclachlan\OneDrive - Unitec IT Solutions\Documents\dev\services.py", line 25, in Find_Service
    s.Change(change_CMD + passwd)
  File "C:\Users\lmaclachlan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 473, in __call__
    handle_com_error()
  File "C:\Users\lmaclachlan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 258, in handle_com_error
    raise klass(com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemProperty', 'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below to change the password using python and it seems work for me.

```
conn = wmi.WMI(hostname, user=username, password=password)
print(hostname+" Connection established.")   #works..
for s in conn.Win32_Service(Name=serviceName):
    changeErrReturn = s.Change(StartPassword=newPasswd)
    print('password changed', changeErrReturn)
```